# Project configuration in Visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013

I have three levels application, supposed to be used by a windows mobile app. A C library(configured as static library) used by a C++ middleware (through a reference of course, and created as a dll). Then i have a wrapper c++/cli to map the unmanaged code to a managed code.

Thus, the wrapper is using the dll (through a reference).

Now, when running my C# test using the wrapper, i am having those errors :

- error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
- plus it is not seeing the wrapper.exe

Any help ???

Thanks

Comment: _'error LNK1561: entry point must be defined'_ Sounds like you either missed to define a `main()` executable, or a [DlMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx) entry point for your application/DLL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you misunderstand the term "module". There is no such C++ project in Visual Studio; C++ projects may be divided into three categories:

```
Programs - compilation produces an exe file, which may be executed;
Static libraries - compilation produces a lib file, which may be included in another project and are linked during the compilation;
Dynamic libraries - compilation produces a dll file, which may be attached to your program at run-time and provide additional functionality.
```

From your description, you want the projectB and projectC to be a static libraries, but instead you created them as executable files. Run the new project wizard again and choose "static library" instead of "Windows application".

You can read more about static libraries in the MSDN library.

If static libraries are too heavyweight for your application, you may simply include projectB and projectC files in your project (optionally take care of namespaces not to confuse the names of classes). It all depends on how much functionality you plan to implement in these "modules".